# How do I stop eclipse from automatically starting up an android emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse

Lately, when I try to run or debug my app, instead of opening the "Android Device Chooser" dialog, like it should, it instead automatically starts up a random (useless) emulator and tries to install my app on that.

This problem kind of comes and goes, and eventually Eclipse starts behaving again and gives me the option to install the app on my phone and/or *choose* which emulator I want to start up and use.  But when the problem does come up again, is there a way that I can fix it or force Eclipse to show the Android Device Chooser?

Comment: I have the same problem.  The emulator is OK, and works for quick tests.  But it's SO slow, and takes forever to launch.  Meanwhile the app is done compiling in 5 seconds.  I just manaully download it to my tablet or phone, and kill the emulator as soon as it pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just gotta right click on the project you're going to run, hover over "run as" and on the bottom of the menu you'll see "Run Configurations".

Click on that and check the box Always Prompt to pick device.

It should look like this:

[image]